# X number of goroutines to update the same variable

Tags: go, concurrency, race-condition

I want to make X number of goroutines to update `CountValue` using parallelism (numRoutines are as much as how many CPU you have).

Solution 1:

```
func count(numRoutines int) (countValue int) {
    var mu sync.Mutex
    k := func(i int) {
        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()
        countValue += 5
    }
    for i := 0; i < numRoutines; i++ {
        go k(i)
    }
```

It becomes a data race and the returned `countValue = 0`.

Solution 2:

```
func count(numRoutines int) (countValue int) {
    k := func(i int, c chan int) {
        c <- 5
    }
    c := make(chan int)
    for i := 0; i < numRoutines; i++ {
        go k(i, c)
    }

    for i := 0; i < numRoutines; i++ {
        countValue += <- c
    }
    return
}
```

I did a benchmark test on it and doing a sequential addition would work faster than using goroutines. I think it's because I have two for loops here as when I put `countValue += <- c` inside the first for loop, the code runs faster.

Solution 3:

```
func count(numRoutines int) (countValue int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    c := make(chan int)

    k := func(i int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        c <- 5
    }
    for i := 0; i < numShards; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go k(i)
    }

    go func() {
        for i := range c {
            countValue += i
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    return
}
```

Still a race count :/

Is there any way better to do this?

Comment: pedantic comment: concurrency is not parallelism

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, I know that! Concurrency allows parallelism, but it doesn't mean they are the same.

Comment: Your mutex lock and waitgroup vars in the attempts are held globally, each goroutine needs a pointer to those vars to work. Something like https://play.golang.org/p/mTYqE6JUvbc

Comment: PS: the race detector is complaining in your last snippet because you're spinning up a routine that iterates over the channel `c` in a `range` loop that never can terminate, because the channel is never closed. Also when `wg.Wait()` returns, all you know is that the last routine writing to the channel has terminated, but the `countValue += i` statement may not have been executed yet. You should close the channel after `wg.Wait()`, and have a mechanism to confirm that the last routine has completed (or move it out of the routine). I'll update my answer with a fix for that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There definitely is a better way to safely increment a variable: using `sync/atomic`:

```
import "sync/atomic"

var words int64
k := func() {
    _ = atomic.AddInt64(&words, 5) // increment atomically
}
```

Using a channel basically eliminates the need for a mutex, or takes away the the risk of concurrent access to the variable itself, and a waitgroup here is just a bit overkill

### Channels:

```
words := 0
done := make(chan struct{}) // or use context
ch := make(chan int, numRoutines) // buffer so each routine can write
go func () {
    read := 0
    for i := range ch {
        words += 5 // or use i or something
        read++
        if read == numRoutines {
            break // we've received data from all routines
        }
    }
    close(done) // indicate this routine has terminated
}()
for i := 0; i < numRoutines; i++ {
    ch <- i // write whatever value needs to be used in the counting routine on the channel
}
<- done // wait for our routine that increments words to return
close(ch) // this channel is no longer needed
fmt.Printf("Counted %d\n", words)
```

As you can tell, the `numRoutines` no longer is the number of routines, but rather the number of writes on the channel. You can move that to individual routines, still:

```
for i := 0; i < numRoutines; i++ {
    go func(ch chan<- int, i int) {
        // do stuff here
        ch <- 5 * i // for example
    }(ch, i)
}
```

### WaitGroup:

Instead of using a context that you can cancel, or a channel, you can use a waitgroup + atomic to get the same result. The easiest way IMO to do so is to create a type:

```
type counter struct {
    words int64
}

func (c *counter) doStuff(wg *sync.WaitGroup, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    _ = atomic.AddInt64(&c.words, i * 5) // whatever value you need to add
}

func main () {
    cnt := counter{}
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(numRoutines) // create the waitgroup
    for i := 0; i < numRoutines; i++ {
        go cnt.doStuff(&wg, i)
    }
    wg.Wait() // wait for all routines to finish
    fmt.Println("Counted %d\n", cnt.words)
}
```

---

#### Fix for your third solution

As I mentioned in the comment: your third solution is still causing a race condition because the channel `c` is never closed, meaning the routine:

```
go func () {
    for i := range c {
        countValue += i
    }
}()
```

Never returns. The waitgroup also only ensures that you've sent all values on the channel, but not that the `countValue` has been incremented to its final value. The fix would be to either close the channel after `wg.Wait()` returns so the routine can return, and add a `done` channel that you can close when this last routine returns, and add a `<-done` statement before returning.

```
func count(numRoutines int) (countValue int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    c := make(chan int)

    k := func(i int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        c <- 5
    }
    for i := 0; i < numShards; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go k(i)
    }

    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for i := range c {
            countValue += i
        }
        close(done)
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
    <-done
    return
}
```

This adds some clutter, though, and IMO is a bit messy. It might just be easier to just move the `wg.Wait()` call to a routine:

```
func count(numRoutines int) (countValue int) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    c := make(chan int)

    // add wg as argument, makes it easier to move this function outside of this scope
    k := func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, i int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        c <- 5
    }
    wg.Add(numShards) // increment the waitgroup once
    for i := 0; i < numShards; i++ {
        go k(&wg, i)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(c) // this ends the loop over the channel
    }()
    // just iterate over the channel until it is closed
    for i := range c {
       countValue += i
    }
    // we've added all values to countValue
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations really helpful!

Comment: @aujau no worries. I've added 2 possible fixes for your third solution which should not cause any data races. I'm assuming you're starting to learn how to use goroutines, channels, etc... They're not super-difficult, but perhaps because of their simplicity, it's quite easy to write a data-race that isn't straightforward to spot sometimes. We've all had to learn this stuff at some point or another

Comment: @aujau Also: on the face of things, your question may look like a basic one, but it's a rare example of an actual GOOD SO question. Something we've not seen many of recently. Showing effort on your part, including snippets showing what you've tried, clear description of the problem, and being open to the idea that you may have missed another way of solving the issue. Maybe SO should add a feature giving bounty-style rep to questions like this

Comment: Yes I'm actually quite new to golang, so I was trying out different methods to see if they are equivalent. That's why there were so many snippets of codes.